# Is -prepareToPlay of AVAudioPlayer to be called in a background queue?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

This preparation method returns BOOL on success and audio files are heavy to load. I suppose it is not a good idea to do this on the main thread. So is it fine to call this in the background and report to the main queue when this method returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fine to do that, i am doing that in a project of mine for the same reasons.